# EF Core fail to load entity with nullable string value

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I am having an issue retrieving any records which have a null string value from the database. I am using SQL Server 2012, .NET 5.0.

My model class:

```
public class Project
{
    public int ProjectId { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50)]
    public string ProjectSaleTypeId { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public ProjectSaleType ProjectSaleType { get; set; }
}

public class ProjectSaleType
{

    [StringLength(50)]
    public string ProjectSaleTypeId { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public ICollection<Project> Projects { get; set; }
}
```

Then when I make a request to get the entity with id `365`:

```
_context.Projects.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ProjectId == 365);
```

the following error occurs:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'An error occurred while reading a database value for property 'Project.ProjectSaleTypeId'. The expected type was 'System.String' but the actual value was null.'

It should be noted that entities which have a `ProjectSaleTypeId` are working properly.

I understand that C# 8.0 introduced nullable reference types. But I have not enabled these in my project; https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/nullable-reference-types

Why do I get this error when retrieving a entity with the `ProjectSaleTypeId` equal to null?

Comment: How is your mapping done? Any added conventions?

Comment: I have no mappings configured for `Project` using the modelBuilder during the `OnModelCreating`

Comment: Is `ProjectSaleTypeId` a fk?

Comment: Yes, `ProjectSaleTypeId` is a foreign key that is nullable.

Comment: Have you tried forcing it in `OnModelCreating`? `modelBuilder.Entity<Project>().Property(m => m.ProjectSaleTypeId).IsOptional();`

Comment: I added `modelBuilder.Entity<Project>().Property(m => m.ProjectSaleTypeId).IsRequired(false);` and now it works. But why do I need to annotate with this? Is there a way to do this on the entity itself instead of in the modelBuilder?

Comment: Honestly I've no clue, more than likely something to do with the member being a nav FK. Maybe someone will chime in with a proper explanation.

Comment: If the model is exactly as shown, the FK should be treated as nullable. If EFC treats it as non nullable, then there must be something telling it to do so, for instance `[Required]` attribute on  `ProjectSaleType` navigation property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error means that the ProjectSaleTypeId is a non-nullable string property but your database table is allowing NULL values for that column.

If EF is handling your database it should not happen, but it might occur that you accidentally changed the DB column type and didn't migrate properly.

Comment: I am not using migrations. Do I need to indicate this in some way to EF? Also; the `ProjectSaleTypeId` is a varchar(50) nullable in the database. My understanding was that my datamodel IS allowing for nullable values using `string` as I have not turned on nullable reference types.